# magento profile debugg : db_update what is it

Tags: profiler

i was trying to debug slow reason fro my magento website in profile i got below output
there was large with **db_update**, can u tell `db_update` is used or what is that need or seems bit odd to me

```
layout/db_update: default   4.8821  1   0   0
CORE::create_object_of::Mage_Core_Model_Resource_Layout 0.0002  11  6,200   0
layout/db_update: STORE_french  4.8806  1   0   0
layout/db_update: THEME_frontend_smartwave_legenda  4.8796  1   0   0
layout/package_update: catalog_product_view 0.0078  1   32,392  0
layout/db_update: MAP_popup 4.8771  1   0   0
layout/db_update: MAP_price_msrp_item   4.8760  1   0   0
layout/db_update: SHORTCUT_popup    4.8747  1   0   0
layout/db_update: SHORTCUT_uk_popup 4.8732  1   0   0
layout/db_update: catalog_product_view  4.8712  1   0   0
layout/db_update: PRODUCT_TYPE_simple   4.8700  1   0   0
layout/db_update: PRODUCT_17    4.8690  1   0   0
layout/db_update: customer_logged_out   4.8677  1   0   0
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I haven't seen this kinda profiled output. But I would recommend you to use Aoe profiler which will give you enough details.